# Script to rename files using a sha1() hash of their filename

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I'm building a website and I would like to hash the filenames of my images.

How can I create a bash script file that renames every file in a directory with the sha1 of the old filename ?

I've tried :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
    newfile="openssl sha1 $file"
    mv "$file" $newfile"
  fi
done
```

But that doesn't work :(

**EDIT**

Based on suggestions here I tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in old_names/*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
    newfile=$(openssl sha1 $file | awk '{print $2}')
    cp $file new_names/$newfile.png
  fi
done
```

This does rename the files, but I'm not sure what has been used to hash the file name. Did the extention get hashed ? did the path ?

**INFO**

I will then use PHP's sha1() function to display the images :

```
echo "<img src=\"images/".sha1("$nbra-$nbrb-".SECRET_KEY).".png\" />\n";
```

Comment: Do the filenames contain space characters?

Comment: 'nothing gets renamed' and 'no'

Comment: Works for me. Does new_names exist? Silly question, i know.

Comment: Is it possible to get the sha1 of the filename without folders or extentions ?

Comment: Close, but no cigar. set `$newfile` using backticks, or their bash equivalent `$()`, remembering to quote `$file` in case it contrains spaces (`newfile=$(openssl sha1 "$file")`). Lastly you seem to have missed a quote off your rename line. Noting that you want the last word of `$newfile`, `mv "$file" "${newfile##* }"`.

Comment: @bobbogo: Actually, `$()` is POSIX so it's supported in most modern shells.

Comment: Why would someone want this? How will you deal with doubles in the future? Another logo.gif will just overwrite the first one? At least hashing the image itself will garantee that each unique file exists only once, and two files with the same (original) name will not mix up...

Comment: sorry, ignore my last comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code examples in the answers so far and in your edit hash the *contents* of the file. If you want to create filenames that are hashes of the previous filename, not including the path or extension, then do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in old_names/*
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        base=${file##*/}
        noext=${base%.*}
        newfile=$(printf '%s' "$noext" | openssl sha1)
        cp "$file" "new_names/$newfile.png"
    fi
done
```

Comment: that's weird .. it seems that php's sha1() function doesn't return the same hashes ..

Comment: @Manu: Oops! Sorry! That should be `printf '%s' "$noext"`.

Comment: On a new ubuntu machine, the script renames files as "(stdin)= 1f558fe589c204f1f9d51becb749a6a10f8db6f8".

Comment: I added : printf '%s' "$noext" | openssl sha1 | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: The above two comments from the OP are important. This is because a newer version of OpenSSL changed the output. Refer to this question for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/openssl-dgst-sha1-producing-an-extraneous-stdin-prefix-and-trailing-new

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
newfile=$(openssl sha1 $file | awk '{print $2}')
mv $file $newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same sorta thing but the snippets here weren't /exactly/ what I needed, plus I'm brand new to bash scripting...  sorry...  In the end I stuck several ideas together into the script that does what I need which is -- look at the files in ./pics and rename them to their old hash while maintaining the current extension.  I've tested this on a bunch of different pictures and so far it works as intended.  I imagine another newbie such as myself would be able to copy/paste this in and be good to go if your end result happens to be the same as mine.  Thanks everyone for the help!

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./pics/*
  do
    newfile=$(openssl sha1 $file | awk '{print $2}')
    ext=${file##*.}
    mv "$file" "./pics/$newfile"."$ext"
  done
```

Comment: sorry, but this script seems to delete files with multiple spaces/dots in their names. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
newfile=$(openssl sha1 $file)    
mv "$file" "${newfile##*= }"
```